# Matrix completion — missing diagonal elements

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-completion

If I have all the elements of an $N\times N $ complex valued matrix except for the diagonal elements (e.g. I have $N^2-N$ elements out of the $N^2$ elements), is there anyway I could complete those diagonal elements if I know the rank of the matrix $r$ ?

How will the solution (if any) be different if the matrix was noisy (i.e. the matrix is the sum of a rank-$r$ matrix + noise)?

Thanks.

Comment: If you know the rank you can certainly get some bounds on the diagonal elements via the Gershgorin Circle Theorem. For instance, if you know that the rank is $k$, then at most $k$ Gershgorin disks can be in clusters that do not intersect the origin. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem (specifically the section on "Strengthening the theorem").

Comment: The rank of a matrix is a numerically unstable quantity (since it is always integral, it must jump whenever it changes), so not suited for a problem involving noise. Also the given entries already determine a certain number of minors that either do not involve diagonal entries at all or in which diagonal entries are multiplied by a factor $0$. The nonzero ones among these minors place a lower limit to the possible rank you can get. Probably you can get any remaining rank in some way, which will almost never be unique. I don't think it is clear what the question asks.

Comment: @ZackC Thanks for the comment, will certainly look into this theorem.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Thanks. I don't get, however, how the given entries determine some minors. I mean since all the diagonal elements are missing, whenever you remove a row and a column, you still have missing elements, so how can you calculate a minor? 
Also, let's forget about the noise part, my question simply is: will the knowledge of the rank of the matrix help complete the missing diagonal elements?

Comment: Well, when you keep say rows $1$ and $3$, and columns $2$ and $5$ of some square matrix (of size $5$ or more), then its determinant is a $2\times2$ minor that involves no diagonal entries at all; if it is nonzero, then the matrix will have rank${}\geq2$ for _any_ way to fill in the main diagonal. Such minors are never larger than half the size of the original matrix, but in the answer by JeanMarie the $n-1$ minor from removing the first column and the last row is always $1$, no matter what you put on the (original) diagonal, even though most of the diagonal entries do remain in the sub-matrix.

Comment: To answer the question: knowing the rank does provide information (and therefore some restriction on what you can have on the main diagonal) but almost never enough information to know precisely what is on that diagonal. This is not surprising: the rank can take only a few (integer) values, while there are infinitely many ways to fill the diagonal; if some value of the rank would pick out just one possibility for the diagonal, that would be truly exceptional.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I get what you mean, it's convincing. So let's give up on this general question and try to have a more specific setting. Will the conclusion be the same if the matrix (whose diagonal elements are missing) is known to have a rank $r$ AND symmetric? Is it still impossible to get the diagonal elements (even to a certain range)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All matrices in the following are $N \times N$.

Let us give the name $V$ to the set of matrices having all their diagonal entries equal to $0$. Let $W$ be the set of  diagonal matrices.

The question can be reformulated so:

> For every $A \in V$, for a given $r$, is it possible to find $B \in W$ such that rank$(A+B)=r$ ?

The answer is no; there exist even some $A \in V$, such that, for any $B \in W$, rank$(A+B) \geq N-1.$ Here is an example of such an $A$ :

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&0&\cdots&0&0\\0&0&1&0&\cdots&0&0\\0&0&0&1&\cdots&0&0\\\cdots&&&&&&\cdots\\\cdots&&&&&&\cdots\\0&0&0&0&\cdots&0&1\\0&0&0&0&\cdots&0&0   \end{pmatrix}$$

(Entries $A_{ij}=0$ but the $A_{i,i+1}, i=1,... N-1$ equal to $1$).

Whatever $B=diag(a_1,a_2,\cdots a_n) \in W$, rank$(A+B)\geq N-1$.

The reason is that the $(N-1) \times (N-1)$ upperright block of $A+B$ is a triangular matrix with ones on its diagonal, thus with determinant 1, therefore invertible in all cases.

Comment: Thanks @JeanMarie. 
I am not sure what property are you referring to in your answer. My question was: if the diagonal elements of a matrix are missing, will the knowledge of the rank of the matrix help determine those missing elements? I would appreciate it if you could clarify your answer more. 
Thanks.

Comment: It's true that the word "property" in my answer does not refer to anything that you have labelled as such. I am going to modify the introduction of my answer, in order to be clearer.

Comment: This is done ; I have even completely re-written my answer.

Comment: Now that I have given a new answer, I see your question is hopefully different : Do you mean that you are given a rank $r$ matrix $A \in V$ (with my notations), and you want to know under which conditions the rank of $A+B$ ($B \in W$) is **preserved** ? Is this interpretation correct ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed response. Actually the question that you posed in the original answer is exactly what I meant, not the other interpretation. 
I am now convinced that the answer is generally no. So let's focus on a more specific setting, will the answer still be "No" if $V$ is the set of all matrices whose diagonal elements are $0$ AND are symmetric ? The counter example that you provided earlier will not be valid then, is there a counterexample (or hopefully a proof) for the new more specific setting?. Thanks.

Comment: The same kind of counterexample would be obtained by symmetrizing the matrix $A$ given in the answer (i.e., replacing $A$ by $A+A^T$)